# FOR command won't run in .cmd file, but runs at command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

When I try to run `file.cmd` containing the following:

```
for /l %m in (1,1,1) do @for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %a in ('findstr /n /r "^" csv\data.csv ^| findstr /r "^%m:"') do @echo %b >csv\header.csv
```

I get this error:

```
" m:")'. Unexpected at this time
```

But when I run that same command at a command prompt (no `.cmd` file), it works.

Comment: in Batch files, use the `for` variables with two percent-signs: `%%m` instead of `%m`. This info is well hidden in `for /?`.

Comment: Eighth line in my help file.

Comment: Thanks, working. But i needed also to change other variables to %% to get it work.

Comment: @code_r, what do you mean by that last comment?

Comment: @Squashman`%%a` and `%%b` (I hope)

Comment: @Stephan, I guess so.  But you should not have to type out every single change they needed to make. One example should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, i meant that ones

Answer (score 3):

You realize there is a much much much simpler way to get the first line of a file into a variable.

```
set /p header=<data.csv
echo %header%>header.csv
```